# Best practice for using Returned Value on Function Call

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables, global

Made a basic Python for my utility and it was the first project I made learning how to code, I know it's messy, that's why I am here.

In this [program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shz4A.png), the button below "Upload XML File" calls the function "browseXMLFiles" and the button below "Upload LOG File" calls the "browseLOGFiles" function (the contents of these two functions are identical except for the type of file they look for) and then the "Remove Duplicates" button calls the "remove_invoices" function.

As it may be obvious, the two former functions open a tkinter file dialog where you can find an XML and LOG File respectively.

After finding the file, the path is stored in a global variable so it can be used to do work in the "remove_invoices" function.

For example, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpXdm.png) is what both "browseX" functions contain in their entirety and the global variable is what I am trying to move away from:

```
def browseLOGFiles():
logname = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/Logs",
                                      title = "Select a File",
                                      filetypes = (("Text files",
                                                    "*.txt*"),
                                                   ("all files",
                                                    "*.*")))
global new_log_name
new_log_name = logname.split('/', -1)
logButton.configure(text=new_log_name[-1])
```

My current issue:

I am trying to clean up global variable pollution, so I want my remove_invoices function to take in the return of the "browseX" functions. I tried just replacing the global variable with the function itself (since it [now returns the path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfmnK.png):

```
def browseLOGFiles():
logname = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/Logs",
                                      title = "Select a File",
                                      filetypes = (("Text files",
                                                    "*.txt*"),
                                                   ("all files",
                                                    "*.*")))
new_log_name = logname.split('/', -1)
logButton.configure(text=new_log_name[-1])
return new_log_name
```

instead of using global variables). What ends up happening, is when clicking the "Remove Duplicates" button, instead of using the return item of the function, it calls the function again within the remove_invoices function, making you select the file paths again.

How should I refactor my code so that I can:

1. Prevent global variable pollution
2. Get the result of the two prior functions without calling them again in the [remove_invoices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2XHg.png) function:

Function:

```
def remove_invoices():
    try:
        error_file = open(browseLOGFiles(), "r") #This is closed later, I promise
    except Exception as e:
        if e == "name 'logname' is not defined":
            statusLabel.configure(text="Please upload a LOG(.txt) file.")
    try:
        global tree
        tree = ET.parse(browseXMLFiles)
        print(f'Opened {browseXMLFiles}. Parsing.')
    except:
        print(f"Can't find file the specified XML File. Was the filename typed exactly, including the extension?")
```

Comment: Don't post code as images. Type the text.

Answer (score 0):

I've long figured this out but I might as well put this to rest.

My solution essentially was to move anything relating to opening files into its own class named FileHandler. I don't have the exact code on hand but I will replicate it here:

```
class FileHandler:
  def __init__(self):
    self.log_name = None
    self.tree = None

  def browseLOGFiles() -> None:
    logname = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/Logs",title = "Select a File",filetypes = (("Text files","*.txt*"),("all files","*.*")))
    new_log_name = logname.split('/', -1)
    logButton.configure(text=new_log_name[-1])
    self.log_name = new_log_name
```

Instead of returning the value, I assign the self.value to the log name. Now, if I need to access the current log name, I can instantiate my class and call that value:

```
fh = FileHandler()
fh.browseLOGFiles() # No longer returns value, instead assigns to class var
print(fh.log_name)
```

This fixes my problem with Global Namespace Pollution and allows me to access these variables anywhere I need them.

This was before I did much experimentation with classes, but if you are new to Python, or coding as a whole, I promise they are way easier to understand than it seems. They are pretty daunting at first but make your life much easier.

Comment: This looks like it'll work, but it isn't the best approach, since it relies on your user needing to have called the function before returning it. Instead, it could be nicer to have your function return the value, which can then be stored into a variable as needed by the caller. You could still use the class to cache the value like you're doing here, but could instead modify your function to use an if statement to check if the value has been calculated, and only do the work if it hasn't, and otherwise return the existing value

Comment: @MiguelGuthridge I appreciate the insight, but this was just as simple as I could recall without going and grabbing the code. For context, this was used within a TKinter gui, so the user never called the function, they would click a "upload file" button and that path would then be saved within the class and used for the work that was done after. Returning a value within the function wouldn't do anything since it would be used within a command argument for a tkinter button. Not that you would have known since my initial post was very vague.